# How to trigger createjs animation on slick slider afterchange callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, createjs, slick.js

I am using slick carousel slider which has 5 slides, each slide should trigger an animation after it gets displayed on the page.

An animator has created an animation using Adobe Animate CC and exported the animation in createjs format so it is compatible with html5.

If I try to call the animation on afterchange I get an error:

```
TypeError: lib.FlowerGrowTemplate is not a constructor
```

See the comment below for where the error is happening:

```
/*The error is pointing to here*/
```

Adobe Animate CC generated javascript code:

```
(function (cjs, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [];


// symbols:
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }

.....


})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;

var graphic_canvas_1, graphic_stage_1, graphic_exportRoot_1, graphic_container_1, graphic_dom_overlay_container_1, graphic_fnStartAnimation_1;
function graphic_init_1() {
    graphic_canvas_1 = document.getElementById("graphic_canvas");
    graphic_container_1 = document.getElementById("graphic_container");
    graphic_dom_overlay_container_1 = document.getElementById("graphic_dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("AD6FD640782B2A4DAD43D647860AC61B");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    graphic_handleComplete_1({},comp);
}
function graphic_handleComplete_1(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    graphic_exportRoot_1 = new lib.FlowerGrowTemplate(); /*The error is pointing to here*/
    graphic_stage_1 = new lib.Stage(graphic_canvas_1);
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    graphic_fnStartAnimation_1 = function() {
        graphic_stage_1.addChild(graphic_exportRoot_1);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", graphic_stage_1)
        graphic_stage_1.addEventListener("tick", graphic_handleTick_1)
        function graphic_getProjectionMatrix_1(container, totalDepth) {
            var focalLength = 528.25;
            var projectionCenter = { x : lib.properties.width/2, y : lib.properties.height/2 };
            var scale = (totalDepth + focalLength)/focalLength;
            var scaleMat = new createjs.Matrix2D;
            scaleMat.a = 1/scale;
            scaleMat.d = 1/scale;
            var projMat = new createjs.Matrix2D;
            projMat.tx = -projectionCenter.x;
            projMat.ty = -projectionCenter.y;
            projMat = projMat.prependMatrix(scaleMat);
            projMat.tx += projectionCenter.x;
            projMat.ty += projectionCenter.y;
            return projMat;
        }
        function graphic_handleTick_1(event) {
            var cameraInstance = graphic_exportRoot_1.___camera___instance;
            if(cameraInstance !== undefined && cameraInstance.pinToObject !== undefined)
            {
                cameraInstance.x = cameraInstance.pinToObject.x + cameraInstance.pinToObject.pinOffsetX;
                cameraInstance.y = cameraInstance.pinToObject.y + cameraInstance.pinToObject.pinOffsetY;
                if(cameraInstance.pinToObject.parent !== undefined && cameraInstance.pinToObject.parent.depth !== undefined)
                cameraInstance.depth = cameraInstance.pinToObject.parent.depth + cameraInstance.pinToObject.pinOffsetZ;
            }
            graphic_applyLayerZDepth_1(graphic_exportRoot_1);
        }
        function graphic_applyLayerZDepth_1(parent)
        {
            var cameraInstance = parent.___camera___instance;
            var focalLength = 528.25;
            var projectionCenter = { 'x' : 0, 'y' : 0};
            if(parent === graphic_exportRoot_1)
            {
                var stageCenter = { 'x' : lib.properties.width/2, 'y' : lib.properties.height/2 };
                projectionCenter.x = stageCenter.x;
                projectionCenter.y = stageCenter.y;
            }
            for(child in parent.children)
            {
                var layerObj = parent.children[child];
                if(layerObj == cameraInstance)
                    continue;
                graphic_applyLayerZDepth_1(layerObj, cameraInstance);
                if(layerObj.layerDepth === undefined)
                    continue;
                if(layerObj.currentFrame != layerObj.parent.currentFrame)
                {
                    layerObj.gotoAndPlay(layerObj.parent.currentFrame);
                }
                var matToApply = new createjs.Matrix2D;
                var cameraMat = new createjs.Matrix2D;
                var totalDepth = layerObj.layerDepth ? layerObj.layerDepth : 0;
                var cameraDepth = 0;
                if(cameraInstance && !layerObj.isAttachedToCamera)
                {
                    var mat = cameraInstance.getMatrix();
                    mat.tx -= projectionCenter.x;
                    mat.ty -= projectionCenter.y;
                    cameraMat = mat.invert();
                    cameraMat.prependTransform(projectionCenter.x, projectionCenter.y, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    cameraMat.appendTransform(-projectionCenter.x, -projectionCenter.y, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    if(cameraInstance.depth)
                        cameraDepth = cameraInstance.depth;
                }
                if(layerObj.depth)
                {
                    totalDepth = layerObj.depth;
                }
                //Offset by camera depth
                totalDepth -= cameraDepth;
                if(totalDepth < -focalLength)
                {
                    matToApply.a = 0;
                    matToApply.d = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(layerObj.layerDepth)
                    {
                        var sizeLockedMat = graphic_getProjectionMatrix_1(parent, layerObj.layerDepth);
                        if(sizeLockedMat)
                        {
                            sizeLockedMat.invert();
                            matToApply.prependMatrix(sizeLockedMat);
                        }
                    }
                    matToApply.prependMatrix(cameraMat);
                    var projMat = graphic_getProjectionMatrix_1(parent, totalDepth);
                    if(projMat)
                    {
                        matToApply.prependMatrix(projMat);
                    }
                }
                layerObj.transformMatrix = matToApply;
            }
        }
    }
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    function graphic_makeResponsive_1(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {
        var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;
        window.addEventListener('resize', graphic_resizeCanvas_1);
        graphic_resizeCanvas_1();
        function graphic_resizeCanvas_1() {
            var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;
            var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;
            var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;
            if(isResp) {
                if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {
                    sRatio = lastS;
                }
                else if(!isScale) {
                    if(iw<w || ih<h)
                        sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
                }
                else if(scaleType==1) {
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
                }
                else if(scaleType==2) {
                    sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);
                }
            }
            graphic_canvas_1.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;
            graphic_canvas_1.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
            graphic_canvas_1.style.width = graphic_dom_overlay_container_1.style.width = graphic_container_1.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';
            graphic_canvas_1.style.height = graphic_container_1.style.height = graphic_dom_overlay_container_1.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
            graphic_stage_1.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;
            graphic_stage_1.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;
            lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;
            graphic_stage_1.tickOnUpdate = false;
            graphic_stage_1.update();
            graphic_stage_1.tickOnUpdate = true;
        }
    }
    graphic_makeResponsive_1(false,'both',false,1);
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    graphic_fnStartAnimation_1();
}
```

My javascript code:

```
(function($){
        $('.custom-graphic-slider .slider').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        fade: true,
      });
    $('.custom-graphic-slider .slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
            graphic_init_1();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I hope everything makes sense

Comment: In the code above there is no `FlowerGrowTemplate`, so you can't call `new lib.FlowerGrowTemplate()`.

Comment: There is a flower grow template. It is all placed where the ‘.....’ indicated. The code is too long and so I couldn't post it

Comment: The code is very long but still doesn’t include the part where the error is... that makes it hard to debug! Perhaps you can trim it down to a bare minimum? Just use a very small demo CreateJS animation to see if you can include that in the slideshow.